# IsSelected is not called if i click on the selected treeviewitem that is already selected in WPF

Tags: wpf

when i click  treeviewitem once it gets selected. When the user clicks on the selected treeviewitem  second time but item is  not active in second time what is the solution for that problem in wpf

XAML

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Company" Margin="2" Foreground="Black" Selected="TreeViewItem_Selected"/>
```

C#

```
private void btnexit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    this.Close();
    TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem();
    tvi.IsSelected = false;
    tvi.Focus();
 }
```

Comment: Can you just add an onclick event to the tree view and then check for selected index of the treeview?